# comunication with android and nodejs

Tags: android, node.js

I have android aplication that sends requests to node js server.
when I send a request the server gets it and handels the requets and return a response to the app.
There is a request that asks the server to send data to all other active sessions of other devices.
how can I do this? I didn't find any working example of sending data from node js server to multiple clients, how do I keep all the connected sessions?
what should I write at the server side for doing that and what should I write at the android application?
thanks..

Comment: If you are only using http requests, I think it's not possible.
One possible way would be to connect using a websocket, and send data over this socket.

Answer (score 0):

The question you're asking is not that simple to answer to, because it should be up to you to decide what technology to follow.
My advice is to study websockets and create a websocket for each active device.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting Android Device to the server you need to connect the server using HTTP request, for connecting HTTP request you can use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) library.
When using these libraries you can ask access token from the server and after getting an access token from login or any other call and send that token with all call and according to that token, you can manage sessions in the server.

Comment: in my anroid app i'm using the Volley library. But my problem is deifffernt I need to send from the mobile a request, that request should come to the server(wrriten with nodejs) and server should update all the active sessions.   so the question is how do I do it ? how I save all the clients that concting to the server and then update them with the relevant information?\\